# how to filter arrays inside an object and return the array with the most items inside?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering, javascript-objects

I'm developing an app that requests data from a third-party source by API calls.
one of my relevant data is located in arrays inside an object.

The trick here is that in some calls I'm making to get the data that object contains a single array and in other calls, it contains multiple arrays.

**I need the data of the array with the most items inside.**

in most cases that object contains 2 arrays inside - in that case, my code is working well and I can filter my relevant array most of the time it's the second array - array[1].

but when that object contains a single array inside - that is where I'm struggling to achieve the data.

(The arrays names are random numbers in each JSON I'm getting so I need a generic solution).

here is example

```
object{

 "154987" [150 items],
 "754896" [13 items],
 "265489" [11 items]

}
```

Here is what I have in my code so far which not working with only single array

```
   function getCurrentBsrByObjectKeyIndex(index) {
      product.bsrObjectKey = (Object.keys(asinData.products[0].salesRanks)[index]);
      product.bsrHistory = asinData.products[0].salesRanks[product.bsrObjectKey];
      product.currentBsr = product.bsrHistory[product.bsrHistory.length-1];
    }
    function correctBsrObjectKey() {
      getCurrentBsrByObjectKeyIndex(1);
      if (product.bsrHistory.length < 15){
        getCurrentBsrByObjectKeyIndex(0);
      }
    }
    correctBsrObjectKey();
```

Comment: The OP's example code is not needed cause 1st) OP is looking for a generic approach and 2nd) the code is not the slightest related to the provided pseudo-code data-structure. @Timmy ... please edit the Q accordingly; remove the last sentence and the code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach is as follows.

1. Directly access a list (an array) of all of the objects first level array's by using [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)
2. Iterate the list/array via [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

   - The reducer or callback function compares always two values, the first argument which was passed by the callbacks previous iteration as the back then array of maximum length and the 2nd argument which is the array of the current iteration step.
   - The function then compares the two arrays and returns (to itself into the next iteration) the new or old (depending on comparison) array of maximum length.
   - Using `reduce` one also gets some of its default behaviors for free ...

     > *[If the array only has one element (regardless of position) and no initialValue is provided, or if initialValue is provided but the array is empty, the solo value will be returned without calling callbackFn.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#description)*

```js
function getArrayOfMaximumLength(obj) {
  return Object
    .values(obj)
    .reduce((maxArr, arr) =>
      // this implementation breaks at
      // an entirely emtpy `values` array

      ((maxArr.length > arr.length) && maxArr) || arr

      // // this implementation does never break but always
      // // at least returns an empty array ... [] ...
      // // which might unwantedly shadow the consumption of
      // // broken data structures
      //
      // ((maxArr.length > arr.length) && maxArr) || arr, []
    );
}

const sample_1 = {
  "754896": ['foo', 'bar', "baz"],
  "154987": ['foo', 'bar', "baz", "biz", "buz"],
  "265489": ['foo'],
};
const sample_2 = {
  "265489": ['foo'],
  "754896": ['foo', 'bar', "baz"],
};
const sample_3 = {
  "754896": ['foo', 'bar', "baz"],
};
const invalid_sample = {};

console.log(
  'getArrayOfMaximumLength(sample_1) ...',
  getArrayOfMaximumLength(sample_1)
);
console.log(
  'getArrayOfMaximumLength(sample_2) ...',
  getArrayOfMaximumLength(sample_2)
);
console.log(
  'getArrayOfMaximumLength(sample_3) ...',
  getArrayOfMaximumLength(sample_3)
);
console.log(
  'getArrayOfMaximumLength(invalid_sample) ...',
  getArrayOfMaximumLength(invalid_sample)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you! the code is dynamic now and work great

Comment: @Timmy ... not dynamic ... The code implements an approach which is **generic** in terms of the specified problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
var object = {
    "154987": [1, 2, 3],
    "754896": [1, 2],
    "265489": [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 4, 5]
}
var keys = Object.keys(object);
var highestArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    var obj = object[keys[i]];
    if (Array.isArray(obj) && obj.length > highestArray.length)
        highestArray = obj;
}
console.log(highestArray);
```

Get all property name from your object. Then iterate through it to find the array with highest number of items in it.